# C++ void function

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I have a question regarding `void` and I can't seem to find a clear answer.

As I have read and understood, `void` doesn't return any value.

But here, if I say:

```
void display(int a, int b){
    cout << a+b;
}
```

When I use this function in `main()` as:

```
display(20,30);
```

Isn't it returning value of `a+b`?

Can someone please help me understand the logic behind it?

Comment: Printing and returning are not the same.

Comment: What does your C++ textbook have to say about this?

Comment: void means that the function doesn't return a useful value. If you want to return an int, make the return type an int.

Comment: To return something you need `return something;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> isn't it returning value of a+b.

No, it doesn't *return* any value, but just prints the result at the console.

`void` as return type means the function doesn't yield any value you can use in further computations. If you need to do so, you should use something like

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

and you can use it like

```
int main() {
    std::cout << add(5,4) << std::endl;
}
```

to display the result at the console.

Answer (score 1):

void doesn't return an answer,

Use int instead like :

`int display(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}`

cout will only print the whatever you want to print. So

`cout<<a+b;` will only print the answer

you have to use return statement and use return type before function's name

Comment: The _"answer"_ is a very unlucky term used here.